# Half the code in my script is giving an error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
For i = 2 To 50
ws.Range("K" & i).FormulaLocal = "=if(countif($C$2:C" & i & ";C" & i & ")=1;row();"")"
Next i
```

`ws.Range("K" & i).FormulaLocal = "=if(countif($C$2:C" & i & ";C" & i & ")=1;row();"")`

I am getting error on this line. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What error were you getting? Please supply this, and amend the question, otherwise the question is liable to close even though you have received an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to double the quotation marks within the string (at the end):

```
ws.Range("K" & i).FormulaLocal = "=if(countif($C$2:C" & i & ";C" & i & ")=1;row();"""")"
```